# Medians of a triangle and the sides of the triangle relationship

Tags: geometry

Suppose the medians of a triangle are 5,12 and 13 units, find the sides of the triangle. I understand that the medians meet and form centroid. But I am uncomfortable to apply this to this problem

Comment: Do you know the median length formula?

Answer (score 0):

You can find formulas giving the side lengths given the lengths of the medians [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)#Formulas_involving_the_medians.27_lengths). In particular,

$$a = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt { - m_a^2 + 2m_b^2 + 2m_c^2} $$